# iOS app crashes at alert view dismissal

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uialertview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've a problem with some `UIAlertView` I instance in a view controller's method. This `UIViewController` is presented from another `UIViewController`, and at a certain point I display an `UIAlertView` from an instance method this way:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Upload Error", @"")
                                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"It was not possible to complete the upload, do you want to try again?", @"")
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"")
                                          otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Accept", @""), nil];

[alertView show];
```

I can dismiss the presented `UIViewController` before or at the time this alert view is shown, what causes that such alert view is shown when the presented view controller is not on screen anymore, so the alert view is shown in top of the presenting view controller. Then, when tapping one of the alert view's buttons, app crashes, I guess because its delegate was the presented view controller and it does not exist. How could I avoid this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally when you have OK-Cancel kind of an alert the delegate should be present. In your case the view controller, because you are giving user choice to try again on failure. Hence delegate needs to restart the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Either dismiss the alert view by calling `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` before your presented view controller is about to be dismissed, possibly in its viewWillDisappear: or an appropriate method. Or if you want the alert view to remain on screen even after presented view controller is gone,  pass the presenting view controller reference to the presented view controller and set the alertView's delegate to the presenting view controller.

Comment: So, I'll need to make the `UIViewController` to have a reference to the alert view... or is there a way to detect if an alert view is being shown when the view controller is about to unload/disappear?

Comment: If your presenting viewcontroller is vc1 and the presented viewcontroller is vc2 which displays the alert view, pass a reference of vc1 to vc2. Then set alert view delegate to be vc1.

Comment: I need to perform some operations if user taps "Accept" and update v2's view, so I need v2 to be the delegate, so I'll need either to "kill" the alert before dismissing v2 if it is being shown, or make v2 stop being the delegate before dismissing if alert is being shown, won't I?

Comment: if you do want to update v2 based on whats clicked on the alert, then it probably makes sense to dismiss the alert if v2 is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the behavior you want to achieve.

First check [UIAlertView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/initWithTitle%3amessage%3adelegate%3acancelButtonTitle%3aotherButtonTitles%3a):

> delegate: The receiver’s delegate or nil if it doesn’t have a delegate.

- If you don't want to do 'something special' depending on the user
  action, pass null.
- If you want to do 'something special' depending on
  the user action create a special delegate to handle the user action and keep that one alive.